# What is best angle for pergula support braces?

Tags: woodworking

I'm building a small pergula to give sun/rain cover for outdoor potting station. It is 45" wide (L to R), 27" deep (from wall to outer edge of pergula), and angles down at 8 degress.  It'll be supported by 2x4 braces on the L and R edges. I can install the braces at any angle I want and connect anywhere on the wall. I was about to install at 45 degree angle by default, but suddenly thought maybe a different angle gives better weight support. Any thoughts on best angle for the braces?  Thx!

Edit - Thank you popham for that detailed answer!  Regarding the unclear explanation, I've attached [a photo](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/354377064425391784/) that shows something kinda similar to what I'm building. I should have found that when posting originally. Your answer of 36deg works well for me asthetically, and allows me to keep the support brace shorter (and thus increase its strength, per your explanation.)  It is pressure-treated pine, so maybe the calcuation isn't quite the same, but that seems close enough for the load I've got. Thank you!

[image: pergula]

Comment: The 2×4s sound adequate. Choose the angle that looks best and then check if that works. Do you like how the 45 degrees looks? What's the best aesthetically?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Pressure treated lumber is "incised" in my region to encourage the lumber to soak in preservative (it's got a bunch of skinny 3/8" long slits cut parallel to the grain). If your pressure treated lumber is not incised like this, then my analysis applies to your pressure treated lumber. If your pressure treated lumber is incised, then compare 0.95Emin/Fc to 440 instead of the Emin/Fc from my analysis. For incised 2×4s, 0.95Emin/Fc approximately equal to 440 implies that the 36.7° still holds (subject to the constraints on Fc).

Answer (score 2):

The shorter the compression brace, the higher its strength. As the angle approaches parallel to the roof, the compression load increases to infinity. Calling the load "demand" and the strength "capacity," a best incline angle minimizes the demand/capacity ratio of the brace. *36.7° inclined from horizontal minimizes the brace demand/capacity ratio* of #2 grade Spruce-Pine-Fir. Instead one might focus on minimizing the demand/capacity ratio of a stud in the wall, but the 36.7° is structurally best for the brace.

Given a gravity load of W at the top of the brace and an incline angle from horizontal of θ, the brace demand is

D = (27in)W/{[3.8in+(27in)(tan θ)](cos θ)}.

Unfortunately the compressive strength is highly nonlinear, so the expression will be messy. Chapter 3 of the [National Design Specification](https://awc.org/publications/2018-nds/) buries the complexity in a "column stability factor," Cp. See section 3.7.1. Spruce-Pine-Fir (SPF) is a low quality softwood that people are often stuck with. I'll assume #2 grade SPF without any pressure treatment and in wet service.

Given F'c = (1150psi)(0.8)(1.15)Cp = (1060psi)Cp, the brace capacity is

C = F'c(1.5in)(3.5in) = (1060psi)Cp(1.5in)(3.5in) = (5550#)Cp.

So what is the column stability factor's value? Given E'min = (510,000psi)(0.9) = 460,000 psi for #2 SPF and therefore an Euler buckling stress of

Fce = 0.822(460,000psi)/[(27in/cos θ)/1.5in]² = (1170psi)cos²θ,

the column stability factor is

Cp = [1+(1170psi)cos²θ/(1060psi)]/[2(0.8)] - {"² - [(1170psi)cos²θ/(1060psi)]/0.8}^0.5,

where I used the " as a placeholder for the repeat of the term from outside the square root. See 3.7.1.5 from Chapter 3 of the [NDS](https://awc.org/publications/2018-nds/). Simplifying, the expression reduces to

Cp = 0.625+0.690cos²θ - [(0.625+0.690cos²θ)² - 1.38cos²θ]^0.5.

I now have the complete expression for C,

C = (5550#){0.625+0.690cos²θ - [(0.625+0.690cos²θ)² - 1.38cos²θ]^0.5}.

I could write down an expression for the demand/capacity ratio (D/C) now, but I don't think there's much value in writing it out. Suffice it to say, the D/C ratio is a function of θ and nothing else (W is a constant that doesn't alter the minimum's θ, it only impacts the magnitude of D/C).

Using a graphing calculator I get the minimum demand/capacity ratio at 36.7°. This result is tuned to your 27" depth (and the 2×4, grade, species, wet service, and non-pressure treated assumptions). It is not some sort of universal truth.

Fixing 2×4, wet service and non-pressure treated, the 36.7° optimal incline angle holds for different grades and species with Emin/Fc values around 440—these material properties come from Table 4A and Table 4B from Chapter 4 of the [NDS Supplement](https://awc.org/publications/2018-nds-supplement/)—but only if 1.15Fc > 750 psi for Table 4A species and grades or if Fc > 750 psi for Southern Pine grades from Table 4B.

Simplifying the demand/capacity ratio yields D/C = W/2200#. This indicates a maximum W at the tip of each brace of 2200#.

Comment: I thoroughly enjoy reading your answers, they're always super informative and remind me how much I have to learn. Where did you learn all of these formulas and how to navigate the building codes so well. Would be interested in chatting with you if you're up for it.

Comment: Pretty sure @popham is a PEng…

Comment: @matt, I never bothered with a wood design class in college, so I've been using SS questions to learn it. With enough time and patience, I would bet that more people would have difficulty with the D expression than the C expression, as D requires statics and trig. The NDS's organization parallels good design. Start by sizing framing and then move on to the connections. Chapters 3 and 4 are where to look for the OP's solution. Then when it calls for material parameters, I'm off to the NDS Supplement. Some loading comes from the IRC. If the OP doesn't have much snow, then wind from ASCE-7.